# How to resize animated gif using Windows.Media.Imaging namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, image-resizing, animated-gif

I have been using GDI+ implementation in Asp.Net hadler for resizing images. I've found article [Resizing images from the server using WPF/WIC instead of GDI+](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx) describing that resizing images using Windows.Media.Imaging is more effective (much faster and consume less system resources).

This approach has one more advantage, I can read individual frames from source image, as gif. Here is part of my code:

```
var photoDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(inputStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                                                BitmapCacheOption.None);
IEnumerable<BitmapFrame> bitmapFrames = from bitmapFrame in photoDecoder.Frames
                                                select bitmapFrame;

var bitmapFramesList = new List<BitmapFrame>();
bitmapFramesList.AddRange(bitmapFrames);

var firstFrame = bitmapFramesList.First();

int inputWidth = Convert.ToInt32(firstFrame.Width);
int inputHeight = Convert.ToInt32(firstFrame.Height);

var firstFrameSize= new Size(inputWidth, inputHeight);

//if targetSize is bigger than image Size render image as is
bool targetSizeIsBiggerOrEmpty = targetSize.IsEmpty || (targetSize.Width > firstFrameSize.Width && targetSize.Height > firstFrameSize.Height);   
if (targetSizeIsBiggerOrEmpty)
{
   inputStream.Position = ZERO;
   inputStream.CopyTo(catalogImage.Stream);
}
else
{
   //calculate size of target image
   Size imageSize = SizeCalculator.CalculateImageSize(new Size(Convert.ToInt32(firstFrame.Width),Convert.ToInt32(firstFrame.Height)), targetSize);
   if (targetSize.Width == ZERO)
      targetSize.Width = imageSize.Width;
   if (targetSize.Height == ZERO)
      targetSize.Height = imageSize.Height;

   double scaleX = Convert.ToDouble(imageSize.Width) / Convert.ToDouble(firstFrame.Width);
   double scaleY = Convert.ToDouble(imageSize.Height) / Convert.ToDouble(firstFrame.Height);
   double scale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY);

   var targetFrames= new Collection<BitmapFrame>();
   foreach (var sourceFrame in bitmapFramesList)
   {                    
      var transform = new ScaleTransform {ScaleX = scale, ScaleY = scale};
      var transformedBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(sourceFrame, transform);
      BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(transformedBitmap);
      targetFrames.Add(bitmapFrame);
   }

   //my own method for saving image to response output stream
   SaveCatalogImage(catalogImage, targetFrames);
```

}

But here is a small problem. Each frame has different size and I'm not able to find each frame position according to first frame size. I also need **timing** in target image as is in source.

Where I can find those information in source image?